# CSS3 3-D transform flip cards without fixed height

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to achieve this effect: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/flip/

I've done it and works fine, BUT, it only works when the parents have a fixed height, this is because the front and back divs have `position: absolute`, so they cannot have `height: 100%` because they are out of the flow.

I can take its own height and set it with jQuery, but this takes the responsiveness out and I need this to be totally responsive.

I've tried removing the absolute position of the front and back divs and giving the back div negative margin-top, you can see the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/q6D5f/

But that is also not working in the responsive side, when the ul's are wide enough it looks good, but as soon as you make the window smaller and the li's are different heights the margin-top becomes unaligned.

Any thoughts?

Comment: How is your code responsive, if it only flips the card on hover? Touch screens don't have hover events.

Comment: Responsive is not only concerned of devices, but of screen sizes too, this is a fluid responsive site, and the touch devices do have hover state, it activates with the first tap, the second tap actives the regular click function.

Comment: @Blazemonger it0s kind of the same, but I modified it and works like a charm, here is the new jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/EVsR5/127/